# Show that $\mathfrak{g}_2$ has a dimension $14$ representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

This question came up in an oral exam. During the course we studied a bit of the theory of lie algebras and some representation theory.

The question: show that the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g_2}$ has a dimension $14$ representation, where dimension $14$ means the vector space $V$ where the representation is defined has dimension $14$ over $k$.

Why is this true? I think it has to do with $\mathfrak{g_2}$ having $12$ roots (and maybe the maximal toral subalgebra has dimension $2$? But why?).

I'll be glad if someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: What is that Lie algebra's dimension?

Hint 2: Surely in your class the concept of the *adjoint representation* was mentioned?

Comment: yes, of course knowing that $\mathfrak{g}_2$ has dimension 14 makes this trivial. I should have specified that we didn't explticitly see this fact (I saw it on Wikipedia).

Comment: But you do know that the root system has twelve roots and is of rank $2$, and you must have seen root space decomposition in your class ... what an excellent question to check if you understand what those things mean and imply!

Comment: now I get it, thanks! I couldn't understand why the maximal toral subalgebra has dimension $2$, but now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the simple Lie algebra of type $G_2$, with positive roots $R^+=\{\alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta,2\alpha+\beta,3\alpha+\beta,3\alpha+2\beta \}$.  With
$\lambda=m_1\varpi_1+m_2\varpi_2$ the Weyl dimension formula gives
\begin{align*}
  \dim(L(\lambda)) & = \frac{1}{120}(m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+2m_2+3)(m_1+m_2+2) \\
               & \hspace{1.52cm} (m_1+3m_2+4)(2m_1 + 3m_2+5)
\end{align*}
for the irreducible highest weight module. We easily see that the possible dimensions are
$$1, 7, 14, 27, 64, 77, 182, 189, 273, 286, 378, 448, 714, 729, 748, 896, 924, \ldots 
$$

Comment: We didn't see the weyl dimension formula

Comment: For Weyl's dimension formula see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula). I think it is worth looking at it. Of course there are many other ways to see this, even an explicit $14$-dimensional faithful matrix representation can be found here.